# What is the fastest way to show image in c# that is created by dll?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, memorystream

I need a fast way to retrieve image from c++ dll memory and show it in picturebox using winforms c# project. My current approach is to receive memorystream from dll then copy that to managed stream and then convert that to Bitmap object. This works perfectly but I feel this is not an optimal way.

Is there any other solution to this which would be faster?

Comment: You can't pass the `HWND` to the C++ DLL and have it draw the image ? It's hard to beat that.

Comment: Perhaps I could, but will that create problems of redrawing (invalidate)?

Comment: Obviously the C++ code would have to include an old-school message pump for the HWND, and handle the `WM_PAINT`. That's the whole point, in fact: as the drawing would happen wholly on the C++ side, there's no overhead in copying the image around.

Comment: @MrxMry if you want to draw from c++ you will have to handle everything in  raw win32 api, which can be a pain. You could also have everything in c++ and use an interface like QT (considering that C# is not mandatory for interface)

Comment: @Raxvan I already have whole project in c# and just use c++ dll to generate image because it is much faster than doing it in c#. Would handling in win32 be really so difficult just for updating the image?

Comment: @MrxMry The faster way i know to put pixels on screen with software is to use `CreateDIBSection` and `BitBlt` function combo. Loon at the documentation for those.